# Check if database was created with Add-Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

VisualStudio 2017 Community, ASP.NET Core 2.
I defined a dbContext:

```
namespace MyDb.Models
{


    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here my settings:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

And the startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}
```

I built the solution and then I added the first migration in order to create the database:

```
PM> Add-Migration Initial
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'MyDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
```

But now when I try to access to it in a Razor page, i.e.:

```
namespace MyDb
{
    public class ViewTablesModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public ViewTablesModel(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Blog> Blog { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Blog = await _context.Blogs.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

it fires an SQL Exception:

> SqlException: Cannot open database "MyDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'MyComputer\Mark'.

I don't understand if my connection string is wrong (it should rely on Windows credentials, I also checked the "Enable Windows authentication" in the project properties") or the database isn't there.

I inspected the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS2017 and I have the (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB connection. Does my "MyDb" should appear here? It doesn't.

### EDIT

First error: the database name is case-sensitive. The correct name is: MSSQLLocalDB.

In fact:

```
C:\Users\Mark>sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB
Nome: "MSSQLLocalDB"
Versione: 13.1.4001.0
Nome condiviso:
Proprietario:              MyComputer\Mark
Creazione automatica:        Sì
Stato:              in esecuzione
Ultima ora di inizio: 22/11/2017 11:45:07
Nome pipe istanza: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#1A9E83A0\tsql\query
```

Now the error is slightly different:

> Win32Exception: Unknown error (0x89c50107)
>   Unknown location
>
> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Istanza del database locale specificata inesistente.

I'm launching the application in debug mode from VS2017. It should take care about SQL Server, shouldn't?
Anyway I see a "sqlservr.exe" process in execution.

But trying to manually connect to that database (using an .udl file) still fails.

Comment: It is an issue authenticating to your sql server. Rename a blank text file on your computer to a .udl extension. You can then use it to check your connection to SQL.

Comment: Question updated following your hint. It cannot open the database neither.

Comment: I don't know about EF core, but in EF 6, I would need to `Add-Migration SomeName` followed by `Update-Database` unless some automatic updating is configured. The `Add-Migration` by itself just creates the intermediate code that will be used to create the actual update SQL.

Comment: @grek40 You can make it as an answer. That was my (second) mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is not created by `Add-Migration`. Instead, only the intermediate code with `CreateTable(...)` etc statements is created an can be modified if necessary.

In order to apply a migration, use the `Update-Database` command. It will also create the database for the initial migration.